# scanf() resetting first result depending of variable declaration order

Tags: c, variables, scanf

Why does this not work as expected?

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char louise, peter;

    printf("Age of Louise: ");
    scanf("%u", &louise);

    printf("Age of Peter: ");
    scanf("%u", &peter);

    printf("Louise: %u\n", louise);
    printf("Peter: %u\n", peter);

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Age of Louise: 12
Age of Peter: 13
Louise: 0
Peter: 13
```

But if I swap variable declarations it works:

```
unsigned char peter, louise;
```

Outputs:

```
Age of Louise: 12
Age of Peter: 13
Louise: 12
Peter: 13
```

I've also noticed that using `int` or `unsigned int` works without needing to swap variables, but `char`doesn't.

I've tried putting `printf("%u", louise);` just after the `scanf()` for louise and the value is saved correctly. And if I comment out the second `scanf()` it also works fine...

The "problem" shows on Windows (DevCpp) and Linux (kwrite + make). Is that a bug of the compiler, or mine?

Comment: Isn't %u an unsigned integer? Sounds rather dangerous having scanf squeeze in a 2+ bytes big thing into a 1 byte variable.

Comment: Try compiling with -Wformat (also turned on by -Wall) in GCC and it'll automatically catch this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is your bug, your variables were of type `unsigned char` which is 1 byte, however, you entered 12 which is 4 bytes (a unsigned int), that caused an overflow (implementation defined by the compiler/runtime), and that would explain it overwriting the next variable in memory. You used the `%u` specifier for `printf` which is an `unsigned int`, for a `unsigned char` variable, that is incorrect and does not match up. That explains, as you have discovered yourself, that using an `unsigned int` or `int` works, as there was sufficient room to hold the values on input.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Oh! Now I get it! Thanks!

How do I make to get a number to a `char` with `scanf()`? Or I have to declare them integer?

Comment: @xOneca: declare them as integer. Why did you use unsigned char anyway? :)

Comment: because I know nobody older than 255 years. I am used to use the smallest variable I can, to save memory. I see I can't do that always... :-(

Comment: @xOneca: that's ok. That's a healthy attitude..that would have been the attitude 15-20 years ago...now pc's have a lot of memory...but still a good approach to squeezing a few more bits... :)

Answer (score 4):

Because `%u` reads and stores an `unsigned int`, which is very likely larger than the single `unsigned char` you have. This leads to adjacent values being overwritten.

There is no way to read an integer string (such as "42") and store it in a `char`. You must go via an `int`. Example:

```
int tmp;
char my_char;

if(scanf("Enter a number: %d", &tmp) == 1)
{
  my_char = (unsigned char) tmp;
}
```